# Perché si dice "calcio"?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

In tutte le altre principali lingue neolatine [1], il nome del gioco del calcio è la traslitterazione locale di *football*:

- Francese: *football*
- Spagnolo: *fútbol*
- Portoghese: *futebol*
- Catalano: *futbol*
- Rumeno:    *fotbal*

Come mai l'italiano usa invece un termine completamente diverso?

[1] Da notare che in alcune lingue regionali questo potrebbe non essere vero: wiktionary riporta il lombardo *ballon* e posso confermare che almeno in parte del Veneto il gioco è chiamato *bałon*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credo, ma attendo conferme o smentite (eventualmente da me stesso), che lo si debba alla combinazione del fatto che esisteva già un gioco vagamente simile e con lo stesso nome, in tempi andati, il calcio fiorentino, e delle pressioni contrarie ai termini di origine straniera nell'epoca fascista (ma anche precedenti).

La voce “Foot-ball” della sesta edizione (1931) del *Dizionario moderno* di Alfredo Panzini dice:

> **Foot-ball** (*fut-bool*): denominazione inglese abusivamente usata per indicare un antichissimo giuoco italiano, che si chiamava il *Giuoco del Calcio*. Pietro di Lorenzo Bini, nel 1587, pubblicò in Firenze un trattato dal titolo: *Memorie del Calcio fiorentino*. Era giuoco usatissimo e nobilissimo. Ho inoltre trovato nell'Ambrosiana un Codice (C. 35 Sup.) del sec. XV, così intitolato: «Qui comincia la Palla al Calcio di Giovanni Frescobaldi», e i primi versi sono:
>
> *Volendo seguitare il mio disegno,*
>   *quasi ismarrito aveva la fantasia*
>   *e la memoria e l'intelletto e l'ingegno.*
>
> Durante la signoria de' Medici furono giocati dei Calci riccamente preparati, ed è fra tutti rimasto celebre quello del 19 aprile 1584, allorché venne in Firenze il Principe Gonzaga di Mantova con la sua consorte, Donna Eleonora di Toscana. Come questo giuoco italiano – di cui gli entusiasti ammiratori potrebbero cercare le origini più remote sin nell'*Odissea*, ove si rappresenta la reginella Nausicae che giuoca alla palla presso la riva del mare – sia venuto obliandosi presso di noi; dall'Italia sia passato in Inghilterra; di qui in Europa, dove col *Tennis* (Pallacorda) gareggia di popolarità, non è qui il caso di ricordare. Qui ricorderemo soltanto come nella patria del *Calcio* e della *Pallacorda* si giochino ambedue i detti giuochi con denominazioni inglesi e i vecchi nomi italiani siano obliati. Dicono gli intenditori che il nuovo *Foot-ball* non corrisponde all'antico e perciò i nuovi nomi hanno giusta ragione di essere. Distinguono il *Rugby* e l'*Association*, due modi di giocare al calcio, questo più costumato e civile, l'altro fiero e violento nella gara di vietare l'accesso al pallone. Si misura il campo a *yards*; i giocatori si chiamano *foot-ballers*; la prima fila si dice dei *forwards*; *goal* la porta per cui gli uni si sforzano di far passare la palla, gli altri di respingerla. Le pene sono dette *penalty*; il guardiano della porta è detto *goal keeper*; il giudice di campo *referer*; il calcio è pronunciato *kick*; *bar* l'asta trasversale della porta; *full-backs* i difensori della porta o terzini, e così via. I francesi oltre che con la voce inglese, lo denominano con voce propria, *ballon au pied*. I giornali gialli, rossi, verdi dello sport costituiscono il pascolo intellettuale di tutte le classi, dallo studente all'operaio.

Quindi, a quel che pare, nel 1931 ancora prevalevano le parole inglesi, per denominare il calcio in sé e alcuni elementi del gioco. Evidentemente la spinta autarchica del periodo, se non imposta per legge quanto meno caldamente incoraggiata da intellettuali influenti come Panzini, deve aver portato al successo, in quasi tutti i casi elencati nella voce, delle corrispondenti parole italiane.

Comment: Il nome della federazione fu cambiato da “Federazione Italiana Footbal” in “Federazione Italiana Giuoco del Calcio” nel 1909.

Comment: *[...] le origini più remote sin nell'Odissea, ove si rappresenta la reginella Nausicae che giuoca alla palla presso la riva del mare*. Certo che pur di prestare antichità allo sport nazionale non si facevano problemi a tirare un po' per i capelli...

Comment: Dopo lunghi tentennamenti ho deciso di accettare questa risposta perché ha delle referenze più precise. Grazie ad entrambi!

Answer (score 3):

Sembra che il termine derivi dal l’antico gioco del calcio giocato già nel sedicesimo secolo a Firenze durante il governo dei Medici:

[Calcio](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lorigine-della-parola-calcio.279166/?hl=it) nel calcio fiorentino dal dare 'calci' al pallone.

> Il fatto che gli altri Paesi europei abbiano la parola "football" per il calcio forse è anche da attribuire al fatto che per loro è un gioco "importato". ***In Italia il calcio nacque a Firenze sotto il governo dei Medici,*** uno dei quali .......  inventò il "calcio storico fiorentino" (con regole molto diverse e brutali rispetto a quelle del calcio moderno) per distrarre i cittadini dai problemi politico-economici che stavano dilaniando la popolazione. Quel calcio, che ancora oggi si gioca a Firenze a Giugno, si è pian piano tramutato nel gioco del calcio moderno.

(forum.wordreference.com)

[CALCIO STORICO FIORENTINO](http://www.calciostoricofiorentino.it/?q=calcio-storico-fiorentino)

> ***Il calcio fiorentino, detto anche "calcio in costume" o "calcio in livrea", è un gioco che affonda le sue radici in tempi remoti [...]*** Il Calcio veniva praticato a Firenze quotidianamente ed in maniera estemporanea da tutti direttamente per le vie e le piazze, con palle o palloni: giocavano i giovani e gli adulti durante le soste del lavoro e in occasione di qualche festa di rione, giocavano i nobili disputando partite "organizzate" particolarmente sontuose e curate nella mesa in scena. Ma la partita più celebre, passata agli onori della cronaca per il critico momento storico in cui si verificò, fu quella giocata il 17 febbraio 1530 durante l'assedio di Firenze, un po' per non interrompere l'usanza del gioco nel periodo di Carnevale, un po' come sfida al nemico assediante.

Comment: Dopo lunghi tentennamenti ho deciso di accettare la risposta di DaG perché ha delle referenze più precise, ma anche questa era ottima. Grazie ad entrambi!